# Query Data from Parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm a beginer, so i don't understand a lot of things in parse.com .
I have a class Photo extends ParseObject , and a table Object photo in Parse.com. 
When i query data from photo i have a problem.
This is my problem:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value may not be null.
```

This is my Photo class:

```
@ParseClassName("photo")
public class Photo extends ParseObject {
public Photo() {
}
public void setPhoto(ParseFile photo){
    put("imageFile", photo);      ///value may not be null.
}
public ParseFile getPhoto() {
    return getParseFile("imageFile");
}
public void setName(String string){
    put("ImageName",string);
}
public String getName(){
    return getString("ImageName");
}
}
```

This is my code :

```
final ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = new ParseQuery<>("photo");
                query1.whereMatches("trade_id",idTrade);
                list = query.find();
                for (ParseObject mPhoto : list) {
                    Photo newPhoto = new Photo();
                    newPhoto.setPhoto((ParseFile) mPhoto.get("imageFile"));
                    photos.add(newPhoto);
                }
            } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And my table in Parse have 2 column : imageFile(File) & trade_id(String)
Tell me how to fix it? please!

Comment: On which line is the exception thrown? Are the values for the variables `query1`, `idTrade`, `list`, `mPhoto`, `newPhoto`, `photos` all valid?

Comment: they are ok, do you see the comment in my code ///value may not be null.

Comment: Can you paste a screen shot of what your table looks like on parse.  Your error statement does not tell much.

Comment: i can't upload a photo .
i have 2 column im my table:
imageFile (File) and trade_id (String)
:(

Comment: I'm not sure what the comment  "value may not be null" means

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value may not be null.

Comment: Oh, so `photo` is null then. Trace that back ... `mPhoto.get("imageFile"))`: is return null. What are the contents of `list`?

Comment: List<ParseObject> list; :( i don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: The `mPhoto.get` call presumes that `mPhoto` has a key called "imageFile", which, given that null is being returned, appears not to be the case.
Experment ... try `mPhoto.has("imageFile");`, see what it returns.
Also try `mPhoto.keySet()` to see if "imageFile" is in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you not supposed to do

```
mPhoto.getParseFile("imageFile")
```

instead of

```
mPhoto.get("imageFile")
```